# Проблема с удалением сущности в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При попытке удаления комментария выводится такая ошибка:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#destroy 
>   Couldn't find Post with 'id' = < Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy: 0x00007f67f0090ce0>
>   
>  Extracted source (around line #39):
>          def destroy
>           @post = Post.find(params[:id])
>           @post.destroy
>           redirect_to posts_path

Мой код:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @post.comments= Post.find(params[:post_id])

    @post.comments.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path(@post)
  end
end

# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'posts#index', as: 'home'

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end

# posts/show.html.erb
<h1><%=@post.title %> </h1>
<p><%=@post.body %></p>
<p>
 <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:thumb), class: 'img-show' if @post.image? %>
</p>    
<hr>
<%= link_to "Редактировать", edit_post_path(@post), :class=> 'btn btn-warning' %>
<%= link_to "Удалить пост", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: {confirm:"Вы хотите удалить статью  ?"}, :class => 'btn btn-danger'%>
<h2>Вcе коментарии</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comments| %>
  <div class="alert alert-light">
    <p><strong><%=comments.username%></strong>: <%=comments.body%></p>  
  </div>
<% end %>
<h2>Коментарии</h2>
 <%=form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
   <p>
     Пользователь<br>
     <%=f.text_field(:username)%>
   </p>

   <p>
     Текст комментария<br>
      <%= f.text_area(:body)%>
   </p>

   <p>
     <%= f.submit("Добавить Коментарий")%>
   </p>
 <% end %>
 <%= link_to "Удалить Комент ", post_path(@post.comments), method: :delete, data: {confirm:"Вы хотите удалить?"}, :class => 'btn btn-danger'%>
```

Comment: А вы понимаете то что пишете в коде? Посмотрите еще раз повнимательнее на свой код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте попробуем разобраться. Судя по вашему вопросу, вы хотите удалять только один комментарий. Судя по вашему коду контроллера, вы хотите удалить все комменты разом. Глядя в ваш код формы, я вообще не рискую делать выводов... Итак, в контроллере:

```
def destroy
  # тут вы пытаетесь назначить неопределённому ещё @post сущность той же модели Post 
  # в качестве комментариев. 
  @post.comments= Post.find(params[:post_id])

  # тут же пытаетесь это всё удалить, но работать оно не будет, 
  # для удаления ассоциации нужно использовать destroy_all
  @post.comments.destroy

  # тут вы видимо хотели вернуться к этому же посту, но написали лишнюю s в роуте
  redirect_to posts_path(@post)
end
```

Полагаю, что вы всё-таки хотите удалить один конкретный коммент, тогда это должно быть:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post.comments.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Ссылка во вьюхе `<%= link_to "Удалить Комент", post_path(@post.comments) ... %>` пытается пойти вообще непонятно куда. `post_path` - это роут к конкретному посту, но ему нужен айдишник этого самого поста, вы же вместо него передаёте ассоциацию комментариев. Как оно должно выглядеть - отображение всех комментов поста, и к каждому уже ссылка на удаление:

```
<h2>Вcе коментарии</h2>
# обратите внимание на название внутренней переменной, она в единственном числе, 
# потому как в каждой итерации мы имеем дело с одним комментом
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div class="alert alert-light">
   <p><strong><%=comment.username%></strong>: <%=comment.body%></p>   
  </div>
  <%= link_to "Удалить Коммент", post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Вы хотите удалить?" }, :class => 'btn btn-danger'%>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

Не доглядела сразу, исправила `posts_path(@post)` на `post_path(@post)` в редиректе. posts_path - это роут к индекс-экшну в контроллере, а вам нужен роут к show

Очень вам рекомендую - прежде, чем продолжать проект, внимательно прочитайте главы про Модели, Вьюхи и Контроллеры в [гайде](http://rusrails.ru/)

Comment: Спасибо вам) но здесь другой вопрос, после удаления комента, меня перебрасывает на главную страницу, а как сделать, чтоб после удаления, комента, мы оставались, на странице поста ?

Comment: @АлександрЛин, обновила ответ, посмотрите